# How to disable UITableView header scroll?

Tags: uitableview, ios4, header, scroll

I created a UITableView programmatically and now I want to add a fixed header to it.
As I the below code the header also scrolls with my tableview.

```
    UILabel *label = [[[UILabel alloc] 
    initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 28)] autorelease];

    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15];
    label.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.8];
    label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
    label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    label.text = @"my header";

    myTable.tableHeaderView = label;
```

Is there a function which disables header scrolling?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you need to either change the view to be a section header (where it will remain at the top of the tableview while that section is visible), or you need to make the header view a sibling to the tableview in the tableview's superview -- you can create a UIView just for the purpose of holding the header view and the table view.

Comment: Thank you, adding it as a sibling to my tableview's superview worked.

Comment: This answer seems to be contradicted by Apple's own Contacts app in iOS 6. In the listing of "All Contacts" the search bar remains on screen without scrolling away. Yet it seems to be included as part of the table view (not separate) because the A-Z index list is drawn on top of it.

Comment: A search bar is a special view/option of a table, not a general purpose table header, or at least was on earlier iOS versions.  Also, the question and answer were posted well before the iOS6 timeframe.

Comment: I tried the sibling approach in iOS 7 - and making the view a sibling of the table view does not stop it from scrolling.